# How can I retrieve strongly typed properties from an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

I'm using anonymous types to pass collections of typed objects to a TemplateResolver, where the named placeholders in a newly instantiated text template may source values from multiple objects, e.g.

```
var body = TemplateResolver.ResolveTemplate(template.ExternalRecipientBody, new {Sender = customer, NewJobCard = jobCard});
```

where the template has placeholders like `{Sender$Surname}` and `{NewJobCard$JobNumber}`.

Inside `ResolveTemplate` I need Sender and NewJobCard to be strongly typed, without knowing what to cast them to.

**SOLUTION SO FAR**

I have come up with this so far, but dislike having to use a string member name.  I have [asked another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395191/how-can-i-avoid-using-a-string-member-name-to-get-a-member-of-an-anonymous-type) on the possibility of somehow lmbda'ring the string out of at least the method call, even if not the method body.

```
    private T GetAnonymousTypeMember<T>(object anonymousType, string memberName) where T: class 
    {
        var anonTypesType = anonymousType.GetType();
        var propInfo = anonTypesType.GetProperty(memberName);
        return propInfo.GetValue(anonymousType, null) as T;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous types only have **method scope,** therefore you won't be able to access the strongly typed properties in the "ResolveTemplate" method.

You've got 2 choices:

1. Box/unbox
2. Bite the bullet and declare a struct/class

If you need "resolve" the properties from multiple sources, then consider using a form of OO abstraction (interface/abstract class) to pass the types around.

Comment: While I agree that this is a good place for a simple DTO-style class, be careful about saying anonymous types are only local.  That's not entirely the case.  For example, you can pass an instance to a generic method.

Comment: @Steven - but what 'type' would the generic method accept? Are you talking about a generic delegate method which accepts type 'object'?

Comment: An anonymous type is as real as any other; it just can't be referenced by name.  So, for example, if you have a generic utility method that takes an IEnumerable<T> and returns a MyList<T>, it would work just fine.  The return value would have to be held in a variable declared as `var`.

Comment: @Steven - exactly. The 'type' accepted by the utility method is still bound by an interface (hence mentioning this in my original answer). Meaning he would need to project that anonymous type into a concrete type deriving from that interface. He can't project that anonymous type straight into a List<T> for example, what would <T> be - it would still need to be a class/struct. Anyway, point taken.

Comment: @RPM1984: No, he really *can* make a `List<T>` without ever knowing the name of `T`.  That's the whole point!  In fact, that's what happens when you call `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()` where `T` is some anonymous type.  The rest of what you said is right: outside the context of the method that created the instance of the anonymous type, you'd need reflection or `dynamic` to get at the properties.  There's actually an exception to this that Jon Skeet pointed out, but it's hacky beyond all hacks, so I'd rather not get into it. :-)

Comment: @Steven - point taken. Forgot about that. Hard to visualize something without seeing code. =)

Comment: @RPM: Sorry, I would have included a short sample that I'm sure would have been clearer than all this talk, talk, talk, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to format comments and I really didn't want to open an answer when this is really just commentary.  Your original answer was fundamentally correct.

Comment: Guys, I have added my solution so far.