# How can I avoid using a string member name to get a member of an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using the following code to retrieve named members from an anonymous type.  Is there some way I could convert the follwing code to use a lambda expression to achieve this, or at least to allow the calling code to use a lamda, even if 'deep down' I have to use a string?

```
private T GetAnonymousTypeMember<T>(object anonymousType, string memberName) where T: class 
{
  var anonTypesType = anonymousType.GetType();
  var propInfo = anonTypesType.GetProperty(memberName);
  return propInfo.GetValue(anonymousType, null) as T;
}
```

**ADDED:**
This is how `anonymousType` arrives.  The `GetAnonymousTypeMember` method is private to a class whose only public method is declared as follows:

public void PublishNotification(NotificationTriggers trigger, object templateParameters)

I call this method:

```
PublishNotification(NotificationTriggers.RequestCreated, new {NewJobCard = model});
```

That `new {NewJobCard = model}` is what is passed to `GetAnonymousTypeMember` as `anonymousType`.

Comment: What do you want to use instead?  Is there another way of referring to a member?

Comment: Something like GetAnonTypeMember(m => m.Person)

Comment: Why not simply use `m.Person`? Why the need to do this in a method, when the only thing the method would do is to call the lambda expression?

Comment: @Guffa, the anonymous type is declared as an object, it has no properties like 'Person' to access, and it is of variable content, so I have nothing to cast to to in order to access properties.

Comment: If it's a dynamic object, you can just do `myObj.Person`, right?  But you're trying to ensure it's a certain type, that's the reason for this?  In that case, use a cast: `(Person)myObj.Person`.

Comment: @ProfK: So you don't really mean anonymous type but unknown type. An anonymous type is still known at compile time eventhough it has no name. You can't use a lambda expression with an unknown type.

Comment: @Guffa, it's an anonymous type, but passed in as an 'object' parameter, so cast as 'object', it has no named prooperties.  I'll add more code to make this really explicit.

Comment: Why not use interfaces and nominal types instead of anonymous types? Why the need for the anonymous types here?

Comment: @ProfK: When it's passed as an `object` it's an unknown type, it doesn't matter if the actual type is anonymous or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public U GetMemberValue<T, U>(T instance, Expression<Func<T, U>> selector)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var expr = selector.Body as MemberExpression;
    string name = expr.Member.Name;

    var prop = type.GetProperty(name);
    return (U)prop.GetValue(instance, null);
}
```

Will enable to to do:

```
string name = GetMemberValue(new { Name = "Hello" }, o => o.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

But why don't You just use dynamic? eg:

```
class MyClass
{
  public int member = 123;
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();

    dynamic dynObj = obj;
    Console.WriteLine(dynObj.member);

    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

You could also involve [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject)

```
List<dynamic> objs = new List<dynamic>();

dynamic objA = new ExpandoObject();
objA.member = "marian";
objs.Add(objA);

dynamic objB = new ExpandoObject();
objB.member = 123;
objs.Add(objB);

dynamic objC = new ExpandoObject();
objC.member = Guid.NewGuid();
objs.Add(objC);

foreach (dynamic obj in objs)
  Console.WriteLine(obj.member);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, when you send the object as the type `object`, there is no specific type information for the parameter. If you want to access the members of the object you need to use reflection to get the type information from the object itself.

Using a lambda expression to get the member would work, but that would be utterly pointless...

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
private R GetAnonymousTypeMember<T, R>(T anonymousType, Expression<Func<T, R>> e) where T : class
{
    return e.Compile()(anonymousType);
}

public void Do()
{
    var x = new {S = "1", V = 2};
    var v = GetAnonymousTypeMember(x, _ => _.V);
}
```